# Check variable type in FreeMarker

Tags: freemarker

I have defined custom macro that contains one argument. It can be a `String` or `List<String>`.

Is it possible to check if it is an array or not ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ok, I found out that there are available a few methods like `is_...`.

Here is [reference](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_isType).

Valid one for my case is following test:

```
<#if value?is_enumerable></#if>
```